# Global Undo and Global Save

Tags: qgis, editing

I work in utility mapping and have recently moved from ArcMap to QGIS.

When editing features from multiple layers that join each other (e.g. a water service connecting into a water main), I'm able to highlight all nodes (being 3 in this instance) and move them to the desired location. But say I make a mistake and move them to the wrong spot in order to undo them I have to select each layer in layer panel individually and hit undo. This is slightly time consuming and annoying to do so as a temp work around I stop editing and discard changes.

Is there a way to undo all the last changes? A global undo if you will. In ArcMap undo would undo all the changes made with the last click.

I might need to ask this in a separate question but is there a global save as well? My workflow for saving is very much the same in that I stop editing and hit save instead of discard in the window that pops up.

I am using QGIS 3.22.13.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In QGIS version 3.22.16 you are able to click the two pencils and it opens up a drop down menu and then you can click rollback for all layers and save for all layers.